# How to make the Java to call a String from a XML file(In Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, string

I have this code and I will like to make it multi language app. What I want is to use the Strings from the Strings.xml file. How can i change "Colombian Peso" to String.

```
        placeHolderData.add(new ExchangeListData("COP","Colombian Peso",R.drawable.colombia,time,"1"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello); // change hello to the right identifier
// then use it in your call
placeHolderData.add(new ExchangeListData("COP", string, R.drawable.colombia, time, "1"));
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#java

You can always change the `R.string.hello` identifier to the right language, i.e. `R.string.es_peso`, based on the user locale, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> String string = getResources().getString(R.string.hello);

Or

> String string = getString(R.string.hello);

to get String from String.xml & add it to your desirable place

> placeHolderData.add(new ExchangeListData("COP",string,R.drawable.colombia,time,"1"));

Comment: Thanks for your help